# Bit manipulation performance: masking or shifting

Tags: java, android, bit-manipulation

I'm not really familiar with low-level (hardware-close) specifics (forgot much).

My app needs to perform millions (or even more) bit manipulation operations in very short time periods, so performance matters.

I need to check if a certain section (consisting of 4, 5 or 6 bits) of an `int` value is equal to a specified value.

I can solve this either by using an `int` as a complete mask; or by using bit shift(s) (to get rid of the disturbing sections) and then doing a direct compare (==). Do these have equal performance? Which is faster?

Comment: This answer will vary based on your hardware; there's not going to be "one true answer."  You have to do the benchmarking.

Comment: I should have mentioned explicitly (even though it's in the tags): it's Android smartphones and tablets, using Java (Dalvik virtual machine). So in 99% of cases, we talk about an ARM processor.

Comment: Yeah, but do you want to bet that individual Android devices won't have different processors with different performance characteristics?  There's _not going to be one answer._

Comment: I'm going to do the benchmark as soon as possible, yes. Would the answer change if I asked "is it reasonable to assume that the performance difference between the two cases is very little?"

Comment: My answer to that question would be "probably yes."

Comment: so what was your decision, Thomas?

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember. But I'm sure it doesn't matter - as Louis wrote, it is probably hardware-specific and the difference will be negligible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking ((a & b )== c) ought to be very fast, and faster than the same operation
with an extra shift. ((a>>n)&b)==c)

It's likely that other optimization techniques, such as loop unrollong, will be a lot more effective than trying to guess what shift and mask operations are the fastest.

If you really care about performance at that level, the answer is to benchmark all the likely variations in the actual deployment environment.

Comment: And what about ((a & b )== c)  versus ((a>>n)==c) ? (My original question referred to this. But I understand if the answer is "depends on hardware".)

Comment: that part of the original question was a bug in waiting, a>>n still has to be masked before you compare it to c

Comment: No, if it has all zeroes on the left.

Comment: that was not part of the problem statement, "section" rather implies the contrary.

Comment: Consider 00000000 00110110 00001110 00000000

Comment: If the section is bits 17-21, then ((a>>16) == 27) should do. But I understand that this is not the general case. (Nonetheless, either the problem statement was "buggy" or implying something else, but it can't be both IMO.) So the question is whether the above expression is executed faster or a bitmask. (The answer depends on hardware I guess.)